# Soul package does not work with XeLatex with Chinese text

Tags: xetex, soul, chinese

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
    \ul{I love you 我 爱 你}     % This works
    \ul{I love you 我爱你}       % This throws error
\end{document}
```

Whenever Chinese characters occur consecutively, it fails with:

> Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `soul` with `xeCJK`, we have `xeCJKfntef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xeCJKfntef}
\newcommand{\ul}{\CJKunderline}
\begin{document}
    \ul{I love you 我 爱 你}     % This works
    \ul{I love you 我爱你}       % This throws error
\end{document}
```

Read [xeCJK.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf) for more details.